# Open eoddata and csv data

Tags: java, excel, csv

i am attempting to download data from the web and access it within java.

It appears to be a csv file.

However when i download it within JAVA, I cant seem to access the data.

Anyone seen this type of data before? When i type the URL into the browser it downloads an excel sheet csv data and it can easily be opened in excel.

It is stock market data. However my code cannot access the data within JAVA.

I have included the code below. Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A_OpenURL 
{

    public Scanner input;

    public A_OpenURL()
    {   
        String url="http://eoddata.com/data/filedownload.aspx?e=AMEX&sd=20171228&ed=20171228&d=4&k=axuiuqhav5&o=d&ea=1&p=0";

            try
            {
                URL yhoofin=new URL(url);//Create New URL data
                URLConnection data=yhoofin.openConnection();//Open a connection
                input = new Scanner(data.getInputStream());
                System.out.println("Scanner Worked");//get data from input stream   
                //System.out.println("This is the scanner "+input);
                //System.out.println("This is the first line "+this.nextline());
                //System.out.println("This is the first line "+this.nextline());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //System.out.println("C This is the symbol i failed on "+symbol);
                //System.err.println(e);
            }
    }


public Scanner getScan()
{
        return input;
}
        //determine if file has next entry
public boolean hasnext()
{
    return input.hasNext();
}
        //contains next line
public String nextline()
{
        return input.nextLine();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    A_OpenURL test1a=new A_OpenURL();
    System.out.println("It worked");
    System.out.println(test1a.getScan());
    String first=test1a.nextline();
    System.out.println(first);
    test1a.input.close();
}

}
```

Comment: _"I cant seem to access the data"_ -- what actually happens? Unless you explain clearly what difficulty you are having, and include any error messages and stack trace, the question is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and clarifying. when  i try to access the data i see this:java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E] I am trying to see the actual numbers and stock prices. i see them when i open the file in excel. Thanks!

Comment: When i try to access with nextline nothing shows at all.

Comment: Instantiating a `Scanner` doesn't magically cause it to read and somehow process all the input.  You have to call its methods to process and extract the input data.  At the point where you output `Scanner worked`, all you've done is create the scanner, it has not actually read anything.  When you do `println(test1a.getScan())` you are printing the scanner itself, not any input data, which you have not read.  I strongly suggest you go back to the Java tutorials and learn how to use a `Scanner` to actually read in data.

Comment: Thanks Jim. it appears i uploaded the wrong version. when i tried to access the read next line it does not seem to acknowledge the read line. i get the error message: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at A_OpenURL.nextline(A_OpenURL.java:54)
 at A_OpenURL.main(A_OpenURL.java:62)
However i know there is a next line because it opens in Excel.